# Spring Boot Cross origin blocking requests

Tags: spring-boot, cross-origin-read-blocking

I have this Spring Boot application with a controller for Login endpoint. I've set these web configurations:

```java
    @Configuration
    @EnableWebSecurity
    @EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true, jsr250Enabled = true, prePostEnabled = true)
    public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {


        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.cors().and().csrf().disable().authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, PathConstants.USER_AUTH +"/**", PathConstants.HELIOS+"/dashboard/**").permitAll()
                    .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/"+PathConstants.PROCESS_DEFINITION+"/**").permitAll()
                    .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/"+PathConstants.PROCESS_DEFINITION+"/**").permitAll()
                    .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/"+PathConstants.PROCESS_INSTANCE+"/**").permitAll()
                    //.antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST,  PathConstants.LOGIN_ACTION).permitAll()
                    //.anyRequest().authenticated()
                    .anyRequest().permitAll()
                    .and()
                    .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(jwtAuthEntryPoint).and()
                    .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
            // custom jwt filter.
            http.addFilterBefore(jwtAuthFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
        }
```

and web mvc configurations:

```java
    @Configuration
    @EnableWebMvc
    public class WebMvcConfiguration implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    private final long MAX_AGE = 3600;



    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/api/**")
                .allowedOrigins("*")
                .allowedMethods("HEAD", "OPTIONS", "GET", "POST", "PUT", "PATCH", "DELETE")
                .allowedHeaders("Content-Type", "X-Requested-With", "accept", "Origin", "Access-Control-Request-Method",
                        "Access-Control-Request-Headers")
                .exposedHeaders("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials")
                .maxAge(MAX_AGE);
    }
```

I've also tried to add `.allowCredentials(true)`, but when I perform the login action it gives me cross origin error and my request is blocked.
This is my controller class:

```java
    @RestController
    @RequestMapping
    @CrossOrigin
    public class AuthenticationControllerImpl implements AuthenticationController {





        @PostMapping(PathConstants.LOGIN_ACTION)
        @Override
        public SysdataUser autenticate(@Valid @RequestBody LoginRequest request) {

            Authentication auth = authManager
                    .authenticate(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(request.getUsername(), request.getPassword()));
            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(auth);
            String token = jwtProvider.generateToken(auth);
            SysdataUser user = sysdataUserService.getUserProfile(request.getUsername());
            user.setToken(token);
            return user;
        }
```

What's missing in configurations?

Comment: no need to specify RequestMapping at class level and recheck addMapping("/api/**") with your PathConstants.LOGIN_ACTION or try to change addMapping("/**") and share your PathConstants

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why your config doesn't override default behavior. this is what I do and it always works for me, change `@CrossOrigin` in your AuthenticationControllerImpl class to `@CrossOrigin(origins = "*")`. let me know if it worked for you.